# How to share private video for a list of emails using YouTube Data API

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-php-client

I need to update an upcoming Broadcast with YouTube Data API. I'm following this guide https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/update

Right now I can change all the `snippet` info with the PHP SDK, but I don't see anywhere how to add trough the API a list of emails who will have access to the private broadcast video (just how we can do trough the panel of YouTube):

[image]

My current PHP try is this:

```
$videoId = $mVideoLive->id;
$liveBroadcast = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcast();
$liveBroadcast->setId($videoId);
$liveBroadcastSnippet = new \Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcastSnippet();
$liveBroadcastSnippet->setTitle("Mi gran titulo");
$liveBroadcastSnippet->setDescription("Hola este es mi descripcion genial");

$datetime = new DateTime('2021-04-08 11:00:00');
$startTime = $datetime->format(DateTime::ATOM); // Updated ISO8601

$liveBroadcastSnippet->setScheduledStartTime($startTime);
$liveBroadcast->setSnippet($liveBroadcastSnippet);
$response = $service->liveBroadcasts->update("snippet", $liveBroadcast);
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Unfortunately, @Fernando Torres, this feature of YouTube's website is not accessible through YouTube Data API. You may well file for a feature request to Google itself (through its [own issue tracker site](http://issuetracker.google.com/)).

Comment: Appreciate the informacion @stvar