# Using Youtube API to share private videos privatized email account

Tags: api, video, youtube, youtube-data-api, private

I want to share a private video with users via email but only mail account owners can be able to open the video with a link even the users share the link, the other users will not able to open the video.

Is it possible with YouTube API?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66991878/how-to-share-private-video-for-a-list-of-emails-using-youtube-data-api#comment118419001_66991878) comment. One is able to view on YouTube website a private video only when he/she has an *YouTube account* and only if the owner of the video allowed him/her to view that video.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the video as unlisted and then the video will not appear for anyone unless they have the link. A private video is only viable to the owner of the account.
Edit: you can chose select people to view a private video https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/157177#private
Thank you @stvar

Comment: Unfortunately, @ParkerAucoin, your statement above -- (quote): *A private video is only viable to the owner of the account* -- is false. According to [official statements](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/157177#private) (quote): *Private videos and playlists can only be **seen by you and the people you choose.*** Go read that whole section as it shows how to *share private videos.*